# How do I access the paragraph value?

Tags: 8

In 1 node. I'm using multiple paragraph type & within that I have fields.

```
Paragraph 1 -> field_title, field_time
Paragraph 2 -> field_test
```

How to access Node's Paragraph 2 -> field_test value?

Comment: What do you mean by access? What are you trying to do?

Comment: To get that field's value which we already have in Admin

Comment: Get it where? Template file? Preprocess function? what do you want to do with it?

Comment: In theme preprocess @Darvanen. I already posted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Need to add below code in your theme file

**themename.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function theme_preprocess_node(array &$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  switch ($node->getType()) {
    case 'article':
      $my_paragraph = null;
      foreach ($node->get('field_content') as $paragraph) {
        if ($paragraph->entity->getType() == 'my_paragraph') { // Change to your paragraph type
          $my_paragraph = $paragraph->entity;
        }
      }

      if (!empty($my_paragraph)) {
        $variable['test'] = $my_paragraph->field_test->value;
      }

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its solved my tasks

Comment: @mike - This is helped me. Could you please tell me how to add main div for a particular paragraph type? Consider, i have node with entity reference field attaching one paragraph type (A). This paragraph type has one field which entity reference field which has 3 paragraph types(B,C,D) attached. Now i need to enclose a div for paragraph type "D". This D type is unlimited, so user can more data in type "D". Suppose if i am adding 4 content to type "D" then i need to surround div for those 4 content. I tried with preprocess node, but not getting exactly where to add. Could you please help me?

Comment: @mike thanks, for multilingual websites this will not work since it will always use the default language. Fixed this by adding the following above the switch

`$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();`

And then call getTranslation() when getting the value

`$variable['test'] = $my_paragraph->getTranslation($language)->field_test->value;`